# Resize image when getting it from url and showing it in an imageview

Tags: android, picasso, image-resizing

Forgive me first, I can not speak English properly.

I used Piccaso library for Android to get an image and show that in an imageview in a baseadapter, but they are high volume images.

What is the best way to resize the image quickly?

Comment: Glide is faster than Picasso.I don't use Picasso anymore.

Answer (score 2):

> try following

```
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
    .into(imageViewResize);
```